# Sitemap Links don't work on live site, Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-security

I have a intranet site with Windows Authentication.  I have 'Administrator' pages in an 'Administrator' folder that will only show for those in the admin group (windows security group)  These pages work

I have a folder with sub folders containing reports.  These permissions are broken down for each type of report.  They have similar role priveleges.  When I test the application, I can navigate to the pages.  When I deploy the site live on the intranet the links don't return a page.  Error missing link 404.  Do I need to set something in IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I don't think anyone is going to be able to explain this to me but for some unreal, unpublished reason, IIS 7 didn't like the folder name 'Reports'  As soon as I changed the folder name (in this case, to 'Reporting') it worked just fine.

Answer: confilcting folder names in IIS.  The webserver was running Sql Server Reporting Services which has a folder for 'Reports' and my website had a folder with the same URL.